# Why is GLFW throwing a segmentation fault?

Tags: opengl, haskell, segmentation-fault, glfw

I am running the following code with Haskell's GLFW library. The following compiles and runs:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  initialize
  openWindowHint OpenGLVersionMajor 3
  openWindowHint OpenGLVersionMinor 3
  openWindowHint OpenGLForwardCompat True
  openWindowHint OpenGLProfile OpenGLCoreProfile
  openWindow (Size 400 400) [DisplayAlphaBits 8] Window
  windowTitle $= "Game Engine v 0.1"

  -- glClearColor 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0

  gameLoop                           
  closeWindow
  terminate

gameLoop = do
  sleep 0.001
  swapBuffers
  gameLoop
```

However, when I uncomment the `glClearColor` line, I receive a segmentation fault. It seems to be GL lines causing this issue - I've tried commenting out `glClearColor` and calling `glClear gl_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` later on in my program, and I receive another segfault.

I build my project like this:

```
ghc -framework Cocoa -framework IOKit Tutorial.hs
```

I am running on OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Why do you use `glClearColor` anyway? It's certainly not intended for user-level, sitting [in a module with both `Raw` and `Core` in its name](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/OpenGLRaw-1.4.0.0/docs/Graphics-Rendering-OpenGL-Raw-Core31.html#v:glClearColor)! I think what you want is `clearColor $= Color4 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0`.

Comment: Sounds to me like context creation fails. Not the only thing that could've gone wrong, but you should probably check if you actually managed to create a valid context.

Comment: @Cubic That was it - thanks. I'll have to dig a bit more into why it's failing but for now it's displaying.

Comment: @leftaroundabout As far as I know, the Raw package is the only one with access to OpenGL 3+ features. `clearColor` seems to be in the 2.x package of bindings.

Comment: @sdasdadas OpenGL support on OSX appears to be a bit sketchy. Although 3.3 should be supported if you have a GPU capable of running it.

Comment: @leftaroundabout In this case it is not fully intended for user-level, though commonly used as the OpenGL package itself is quite a bit out of date. That it contains both Raw and Core in its name is perfectly sensible. The specific module contains the function from the OpenGL Core profile and it is from the OpenGLRaw package (which directly maps the C functions).

Comment: @sdasdadas I don't know what is going wrong, yet I recommend some extra checks that all is going well. Both `initialize` and `openWindow` return a `Bool` if successful, it might be worth checking them. Furthermore, it might be a good idea to check what `glVersion` returns.

Separately, the [GLFW-b](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/GLFW-b) package is a bit more modern and seems to get more frequent updates. It might be worth considering to change to it.